# Is it possible to do old school 2d blitting on modern GPU?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, gpu

It looks like GL has become mainstream for all gaming platforms (even handheld!)
This has pushed the deployment of modern GPU chipsets to large numbers of consumers.

This is amazing.

With the modern GPU systems out there now, is it possible to do generic old-school graphics
programming (aka - blit from X rect to Y rect using VRAM)? (Think Amiga) Or are the operations centered
around vertex and pixel shaders?

Is this accessable from GL?  OpenGL ES?

Rendering a textured quad is OK, but it would require double buffering and a re-render of the entire scene. Was seeing if I could avoid this.

Comment: I have almost zero experience in this area, so this may be a stupid suggestion, but if 3D graphics is fast, and you need 2D graphics, can't you just use 3D capabilities but keep Z = 0 and only let X and Y vary?

Comment: you will NEVER be able to do anything faster in your own code that can be done in 3D hardware, you are wasting your time on premature optimization.

Comment: @Earwicker, thats what some of the answers are suggesting..

Comment: @Earlz - ah, I just don't understand the jargon.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop - I'm asking for the hardware angle. where am I asking to do anything in my own code?

Comment: there is no "hardware" angle anymore. none of those type operations are exposed anymore and if they are, using something like DirectX or OpenGL would be faster anyway.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop - two answers showed the hardware angle exposed via an api. The glBlitFrameBuffer and the old glCopyPixels do full VRAM speed blits by the GPU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for [glBlitFramebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) routine ([Framebuffer Object](https://web.archive.org/web/20100311043758/http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Objects#Framebuffer_Bliting)). You need an updated driver.

Keep in mind you can still use the default framebuffer, but I think it will be more funny using framebuffer objects.

Keep your sprite in separate frambuffers (maybe rendered using OpenGL), and set them as read (using glReadBuffers) and blit them on the draw framebuffer (using glDrawBuffers). It's quite simple and fast.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use [libSDL](http://www.libsdl.org) and get a pointer to the screen framebuffer and do whatever you want with the pixels.
Or you cand do all your drawing to a memory buffer, load to a GL texture and draw textured quads which probably it's faster because of hardware acceleration.

Comment: I don't want a framebuffer, pointer, I want to use code on a GPU to do it all.

Comment: @drudru, have you heard of OpenCL. I think it has something to do with executing arbitrary code on certain Nvidia GPUs

Comment: @Earls - yeah, that might be the ticket. I was hoping someone from that camp might chime in.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible on some embedded systems to get a framebuffer pointer and write to it directly, but these days you're better off using OpenGL|ES and rendering a texture.  It will be more portable, and probably faster.

You could create a buffer in main memory, do all the bit twiddling you want, and then render it as a texture.  You can DMA your texture data to VRAM for speed, and then render it in a quad, which is equivalent to a blit, but doesn't use any CPU cycles and runs as fast as the GPU can process.

It's amazing what you can do with shaders and programmable pipelines these days.

Comment: I don't want a framebuffer, pointer, I want to use code on a GPU to do it all.

Comment: Ok, have a look at the [render-to-texture technique](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=36).  You use shaders to render whatever you like to a texture, and then draw that texture using a quad, which will blit it to the screen.  You can choose from a variety of ROPs too, based on the texture parameters and blend modes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're drawing textured quads, with which you can easily simulate "old school" blitting, then indeed the pixels are copied from video memory by the GPU. Also note that while bitmap operations are possible in OpenGL, they can be painfully slow because the 3D path is optimized on consumer grade video cards, whereas 2D paths may not be.

Comment: Rendering quads has little to do with double buffering. You can use a single buffer if that's how things are supposed to be done on the target device. If the whole frame changes though, you're going to have to update everything anyway.

Comment: true, but for my app, 90% of the operations are scroll. On old school hardware, this would just be a matter of moving the hardware VRAM pointer to a new location with a preset modulo. A fast blit wouuld do the trick as well. In my app, I can avoid a whole redraw. Thx for your answer though.

Comment: @drudru: in the old days you needed to scroll like that because you didn't have the processortime to redraw the frame. Nowadays with hardware, you can redraw the screen many times over and still have time to kill. Especially if you only do '2d' blits

Answer (score 0):

Also, glCopyPixels seems to do the trick if you have the environment set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use the low level bitmap copying functions, which accurate match the old description without any OpenGL, etc.

```
BOOL BitBlt(
  _In_ HDC   hdcDest,
  _In_ int   nXDest,
  _In_ int   nYDest,
  _In_ int   nWidth,
  _In_ int   nHeight,
  _In_ HDC   hdcSrc,
  _In_ int   nXSrc,
  _In_ int   nYSrc,
  _In_ DWORD dwRop
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx